# Problem with restoring database which has a filestream

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2016, filestream

When I restored a database backup file, which uses FILESTREAM feature, everything was fine but after a while the database went to the **(recovery pending)** mode. I tried restarting SQL Server service and it still didn't work. I decided to delete the database and restore it again but I got this error while restoring:

> Restore of database 'Ka4' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: FILESTREAM feature is disabled.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

I've reinstalled SQL Server instance but nothing has changed and it still keeps saying the same error.

According to [this page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1838/different-ways-to-enable-filestream-feature-of-sql-server-2008/) I'm sure that FILESTREAM feature is enabled.

P.S. This is my SQL Server version:

*Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)   Apr 29 2016 23:23:58*

Comment: I don't suppose this is something running on a personal machine, with the Windows 10 creators update is it? There's a bug with that https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Nic.
It seems that there's a bug with Windows 10 Creators Update. After reading [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/filestream-issues-with-sql-server-on-windows-10-creators-update/) I could manage to solve the problem by changing the service startup account to built-in account LocalSystem and now it works.